# Is there a GNU/Linux equivalent to the Mac OS X open command?

Tags: linux, shell, osx, gnu

In Mac OS X there is a handy `open` command that opens the target file or directory in the default GUI application meant for it:

```
open /usr/local/share
```

will bring up a `Finder` window with the `/usr/local/share` directory open in it (BTW I don't know of any other way to open this particular directory in Finder) and

```
open ~/Desktop/example.jpg
```

will bring up a `Preview` window displaying the `example.jpg` file located on the current user's desktop.

Is there an equivalent in the GNU/Linux world?

Comment: `xdg-open`​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Or http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124811/70524?

Comment: @mikeserv you are right, `xdg-open` is the correct answer, thank you. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.